# disable helm upgrade for particular statefulset template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

i have a helm chart having multiple StatefulSet templates.
i want one of the template to be deployed only during `helm install`
and it should not teminate when doing `helm upgrade`.

```
{{- if .Release.IsInstall -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
.....
.....
{{- end -}}
```

as you can see i want this `sts` to be deployed only during installation and also
i want it to be unaffected(not terminated) when during `helm upgrade`

Comment: Helm will normally render the entire chart, compare it to what's already in the cluster, and send Kubernetes only what's changed.  You should normally always include all of the objects (you should rarely if ever check `.Release.IsInstall`) and Helm/Kubernetes won't do anything if the StatefulSet spec is unchanged.  Is there something more specific you're trying to protect against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after doing through helm documentation, it provides solution using helm hooks

```
"helm.sh/hook": pre-install
"helm.sh/hook-weight": "-10"
```

[https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#:~:text=Description-,pre%2Dinstall,-Executes%20after%20templates](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#:%7E:text=Description-,pre%2Dinstall,-Executes%20after%20templates)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following native object function

```
Release.IsUpgrade: This is set to true if the current operation is an upgrade or rollback.
```

You can read more about helm native objects [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/)